# MYSQL SQL (self) join?

Tags: mysql, view, self-join

Using this sample dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE test. test2 (id VARCHAR(7), AA INT, BBB INT, CCC VARCHAR (12));
INSERT INTO test.test2 (id, AA, BBB,CCC) VALUES ( 'A123', 45, 123, '2011-03' );
INSERT INTO test.test2 (id, AA, BBB,CCC) VALUES ( 'A120', 52, 120, '2011-03' );
INSERT INTO test.test2 (id, AA, BBB,CCC) VALUES ( 'A133', 63, 133, '2011-03' );
INSERT INTO test.test2 (id, AA, BBB,CCC) VALUES ( 'D123', 34, 123, '2011-04' );
INSERT INTO test.test2 (id, AA, BBB,CCC) VALUES ( 'D120' ,32, 120, '2011-04' );
INSERT INTO test.test2 (id, AA, BBB,CCC) VALUES ( 'D140', 12, 140, '2011-04' );
```

Im look for table with 3 column.

Col A "Id" order as Desc from orginal.

Col B "Id2" as previous or next row Id in col A where CCC are the same.

```
Id,  Id2  CCC
A120 A123 '2011-03'
A123 A133 '2011-03'
A133      '2011-03'
D120 D123 '2011-04'
D123 D140 '2011-04'
D140      '2011-04'
```

or

```
  Id,  Id2  CCC
A120      '2011-03'
A123 A120 '2011-03'
A133 A123 '2011-03'
D120      '2011-04'
D123 D120 '2011-04'
D140 D123 '2011-04'
```

OR

```
   Id,  Id2  CCC
   A123 A120 '2011-03'
   A133 A123 '2011-03'
   D123 D120 '2011-04'
   D140 D123 '2011-04'
```

Could I add an autocrement col to joined table, then use 1, 2, 3 rows up or down? The id2  would then be based on this autocrement row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating on Marc's basis:

```
SELECT test.id, child.id, test.CCC
FROM test
  LEFT JOIN test AS child
    ON (test.CCC = child.CCC)
      AND (test.id < child.id)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 1
    FROM test AS middle
    WHERE (test.CCC = middle.CCC)
      AND (test.id < middle.id)
      AND (middle.id < child.id)
  )
  OR child.id IS NULL
ORDER BY test.id
```

This might be helpful with more complex queries:

```
CREATE VIEW testWithRowId AS
  ( SELECT test.id
         , COUNT(test.id) AS rownum
         , test.CCC
    FROM test
      JOIN test AS child
        ON (test.CCC = child.CCC)
          AND (test.id >= child.id)
    GROUP BY test.CCC
           , test.id 
  )
```

and then use it:

```
SELECT t1.id
     , t2.id AS idShifted
     , t1.CCC
FROM testWithRowId t1
  LEFT JOIN testWithRowId t2
    ON (t2.CCC = t1.CCC) 
      AND (t2.rownum = t1.rownum + 1)   ---- replace this 1 with 2 or 3, etc
ORDER BY t1.CCC                         ---- for a shift 2 or shift 3, etc
       , t1.rownum
```

Comment: The `child.id IS NULL` can be removed without harm, or I need some coffee?

Comment: @ypercube, Thnks.... Wht if I wanted to move up/down 2 rows, then how would change the code?

Comment: @user428862: not an easy change from my answer.

Comment: Could I add a autocrement col to joined table, then use 1, 2, 3 rows up or down? "(test.id < child.id)" would then be based on this autocrement row?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT test.id, child.id, test.CCC
FROM test
LEFT JOIN test AS child ON ((test.CCC = child.CCC) and (test.id < child.id))
```

gets close:

```
+------+------+---------+
| id   | id   | CCC     |
+------+------+---------+
| A120 | A123 | 2011-03 |
| A120 | A133 | 2011-03 |
| A123 | A133 | 2011-03 |
| A133 | NULL | 2011-03 |
| D120 | D123 | 2011-04 |
| D120 | D140 | 2011-04 |
| D123 | D140 | 2011-04 |
| D140 | NULL | 2011-04 |
+------+------+---------+
```

Comment: He doesn't want that, exactly. Only consecutive "pairs".

Comment: I know, hence me saying "gets close"

Answer (score 1):

```
Select T.Id, NextTest.NextId As Id2, T.CCC
From Test2 As T
    Left Join   (
                Select T1.Id, Min( T2.Id ) As NextId
                From Test2 As T1
                    Left Join Test2 As T2
                        On T2.CCC = T1.CCC
                            And T2.Id > T1.Id
                Group By T1.Id
                ) As NextTest
            On NextTest.Id = T.Id
Order By T.Id
```

This should return exactly what you have in your first set of desired output.