# MySQl creating Self joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Using the answer from previous Question? 
[MYSQL SQL (self) join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750355/mysql-sql-self-join)

Using views is unworkable. The row count is 4000 by 7  cols. 
I can get the table to this form below.

```
"id"    "AA"    "BBB"   "CCC"       Rank   Span

"A123"  "45"    "123"   "2011-03"    1       2 
"A120"  "52"    "120"   "2011-03"    2       3
"A133"  "63"    "133"   "2011-03"    3       4 
"D123"  "34"    "123"   "2011-04"    4       5
"D120"  "32"    "120"   "2011-04"    5       6
"D140"  "12"    "140"   "2011-04"    6       7
```

Still looking for below ans using the rank and span columns 
Span is just Rank +1 or +2

```
    Id,  Id2    CCC
   A123 A120 '2011-03'
   A133 A123 '2011-03'
   D123 D120 '2011-04'
   D140 D123 '2011-04'
```

Comment: How I get 1st table to yield second table using the a rank col, So I can change the Rank and span to get a row two span or one row span. Clear?

Comment: Or use SPan as Identifier for getting ID2.

Comment: Are you sure about the expected output. I get the 1st and 3rd row but the 2nd and 4th have me baffled

Comment: @ conrad, Can you post ur ans? Pls look at previous q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  a.id
  , b.id as id2
  , a.ccc
from table1 a
inner join table1 b on (b.span = a.rank)
```